# bind svg gradient based on data d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I have a bar chart, But the only thing I want is that the color of each bar should be mapped with the data associated with each bar and a color gradient.

say least value should get light green and medium value should white and highest values bar should get dark green color

any suggestions !!

Answer (score 1):

You want to look for a linear scale, that scales a color domain.

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
    .range(['lime', 'white', 'green']);

// ...
some_selection.attr('fill', function(d,i) {return color(d)});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/qLnc27ou/)